# How to set focus on an input field after rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's the react way of setting focus on a particular text field after the component is rendered?

Documentation seems to suggest using refs, e.g:

Set `ref="nameInput"` on my input field in the render function, and then call:

```
this.refs.nameInput.getInputDOMNode().focus();
```

But where should I call this? I've tried a few places but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Don't bother reading all the answers if you are bound by the ESLint rule `jsx-a11y/no-autofocus`.

Answer (score 801, accepted):

You should do it in `componentDidMount` and [`refs callback`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead. Something like this

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.nameInput.focus(); 
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  componentDidMount(){
    this.nameInput.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input 
          defaultValue="Won't focus" 
        />
        <input 
          ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }} 
          defaultValue="will focus"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it did not work for me as my component first renders nothing, until another button is clicked. This meant that it was already mounted, so I had to add  this.refs.nameInput.getDOMNode().focus();  in componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount.

Comment: Why, when element.focus() is called, does it put the cursor at the beginning of the input? I saw this (what I consider a) bug in my app, in chrome, actually in a <textarea> and now checking your demos here it's the same.

Comment: Warning: React.findDOMNode is deprecated. Please use ReactDOM.findDOMNode from require('react-dom') instead.

Comment: How would you go about doing this if you have a stateless component?

Comment: @HuwDavies I guess you'd do it using a [ref Callback Attribute](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) on the `<input>` element.  Something like `<input ref={ (component) => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component).focus() } />`

Comment: I get "Cannot set property 'nameInput' of undefined" when I try to do `ref={(input) => { this.nameInput = input; }}`

Comment: @Chucky have a `debugger;` inside the method and inspect what `this` refers to

Comment: For some reason immediate invocation of `.focus()` didn't work in my app, but with short (insignificant) timeout it did: `componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.textInput.focus();
    }, 10);
  }`

Comment: @Viacheslav Ideally that shouldn't be required. I believe it depends on how your application/component works.

Comment: I found that in 16, having dev tools open puts the focus in the psuedo cli/terminal which stopped the focus from working in firefox. Closing it suddenly made it workign but onl after I had spent 3 hours on trying to under it....

Comment: Why we not just use  _ref={(input) => { input.focus()}}_  ? This solution works fine for me.

Comment: Lazy I am to test this.. But answer from @FakeRainBrigand worked like charm `<input type="text" autoFocus />`

Comment: this.nameInput.current.focus();

Comment: @H.C.Liu that made it focus on every render for me instead of just first one

Answer (score 1207):

@Dhiraj's answer is correct, and for convenience you can use the autoFocus prop to have an input automatically focus when mounted:

```
<input autoFocus name=...
```

Note that in jsx it's `autoFocus` (capital F) unlike plain old html which is case-insensitive.

Comment: Note that in jsx its auto*F*ocus (capital F) unlike plain old html which is case-insensitive.

Comment: Very Good, Got here after a long fruitless search :)  
FYI - I ended up using React.DOM.input({
             type: 'text',
             defaultValue: content,
             autoFocus: true,
             onFocus: function(e) {e.target.select();}
            })

Comment: @RemiSture did you try it and see that it's not working?

Comment: @RemiSture That's an iOS feature. You unfortunately can't do anything about it.

Comment: I find that autoFocus only works on first page render. See https://codepen.io/ericandrewlewis/pen/PbgwqJ?editors=1111 the input should be focused after 3 seconds.

Comment: @EricAndrewLewis the input isn't remounting in your code.

Comment: +1 for this method. It's worth mentioning that this doesn't just use HTML5 unreliable `autofocus` attribute, it actually [uses `focus()` on DOM mount in `react-dom`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/dom/stack/client/ReactDOMComponent.js#L632) so it's quite reliable.

Comment: As far as I can tell, @Aaron's comment is no longer valid. I only see reference to `autoFocus` mapping to the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute now. Perhaps this changed recently to be more consistent with HTML5?

Comment: @DanaWoodman The implementation has dramatically changed but it appears it's still the same strategy: [`autoFocus` just calls `focus()` on mount](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/ac630e4a2f2a6e794c3f9858f606476147e735fd/packages/react-dom/src/client/ReactDOM.js#L719).

Comment: Not only "for convenience" but also if your component is a functional component.

Comment: It didn't do what I originally intended but it's a nice effect if you open the page (it puts the focus in the input field automatically)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - unless you need the ref to do other things with the input, this is a much more natural web solution that doesn't need extra react code :)

Comment: +1 for the note on capital F.  Was struggling to figure out why one component with autoFocus was working properly while another wasn't.  After seeing this answer the lowercase f in the non-working component became obvious.

Comment: By far the easiest way! Works on buttons too

Comment: It's worth mentioning that autoFocus is actually bad for accessibility and can have a negative impact on the user experience.

https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe-linter/1.0/no-autofocus?application=axe-linter-dev

Comment: In 2022 and inside a functional Component / Hooks, I am ignoring @Dhiraj's answer (not using refs callback), and simply using the attribute autoFocus, and it seems to work !? Hopefully it's the correct way to do it.

Comment: It doesn't work at all in my React 18 application. What did work is regular:
```
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current != null) {
      inputRef.current.focus()
    }
  }, [inputRef])
```

Answer (score 351):

## Focus on mount

If you just want to focus an element when it mounts (initially renders) a simple use of the autoFocus attribute will do.

```
<input type="text" autoFocus />
```

## Dynamic focus

to control focus dynamically use a general function to hide implementation details from your components.

#### React 16.8 + Functional component - useFocus hook

```
const FocusDemo = () => {

    const [inputRef, setInputFocus] = useFocus()

    return (
        <> 
            <button onClick={setInputFocus} >
               Focus
            </button>
            <input ref={inputRef} />
        </>
    )
    
}
```

```js
const useFocus = () => {
    const htmlElRef = useRef(null)
    const setFocus = () => {htmlElRef.current &&  htmlElRef.current.focus()}

    return [ htmlElRef, setFocus ] 
}
```

[Full Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/focushook?file=index.js)

#### React 16.3 + Class Components - utilizeFocus

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.inputFocus = utilizeFocus()
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <> 
          <button onClick={this.inputFocus.setFocus}>
             Focus
          </button>
          <input ref={this.inputFocus.ref}/>
      </>
    )
  } 
}
```

```js
const utilizeFocus = () => {
    const ref = React.createRef()
    const setFocus = () => {ref.current &&  ref.current.focus()}

    return {setFocus, ref} 
}
```

[Full Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/declarative-focus-demo-j2xrag)

Comment: This answer contains the right approach for React Hooks. Super! It doesn't typecheck as-is in TypeScript but one (ugly) way to make it work: (1) `(htmlElRef.current as any).focus()` and (2) `return {htmlElRef, setFocus}` instead of array.

Comment: @AhmedFasih, I am aware of what you are saying, but I think it is out of scope for this thread. If you return an object it makes it more difficult to control the name of the variable, which could be a problem if you want to use `useFocus` for more than one element.

Comment: Here is `useFocus` written in Typescript. https://gist.github.com/carpben/de968e377cbac0ffbdefe1ab56237573

Comment: @BenCarp Small suggestion for hooks, might be better to put the `set` in the second position like `const [inputRef, setInputFocus] = useFocus()`. This matches useState more. First the object, then the setter of that object

Comment: @Rubanov, thanks. I adjusted the code per your suggestion.

Comment: I noticed the Stackblitz demo doesn't work perfectly on Firefox. There is no issue when running it locally. I believe it is a Stackblitz thing.

Comment: @BenCarp Hi, I really like your way of making focus but when I try to use your examole in Class based component, I get: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. error. Can you help to solve this?

Comment: @Gido, I'd love to help. But I doubt if it is related to the class method I present, because there is no state update in that example. Can you please build a minimal demo to present this error in an online React editor (CodeSandBox or StackBlitz) and I can try to check it there.

Comment: @BenCarp I am posting the link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-hill-ydgx7?file=/src/App.js Here you can see that I am trying to use onKeyDown to change the focus but it doesn't change and shows the error. Codesandbox somehow doesn't show, however button doesn't change focus

Comment: @Gido, see my comments https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sun-3upm4?file=/src/App.js.

Comment: I tried something similar but couldn't make it work with a custom input item. Could you take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542829/focus-on-the-first-input-item-only

Comment: @jnl, I see that you deleted the question. If it's still relevant let me know.

Comment: This answer works great for html input, but I couldn't make it work for React material ui TextField component. Can you please help me?

Comment: This answer works great for html input, I got stuck for a while using React material ui TextField component instead of the input element. You should use the `inputRef` attribute instead of the `ref` for the TextField component.

Answer (score 233):

**As of React 0.15**, the most concise method is:

```html
<input ref={input => input && input.focus()}/>
```

Comment: This also handles the scenarios outside of the initial render whereas just using autoFocus does not.

Comment: question, when would input be false? I'm referring to the expression inside the arrow function.

Comment: @JaeGeeTee it's null until the component is mounted and/or after it has been unmounted (I don't remember for sure which is the case).

Comment: The only issue with this is that it focuses input on any re-render which might not be desired..

Comment: Doesn't work in my case (using *Ant Design* input component)

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much! -- My case was focusing the text input in React Native, based on a prop that showed the modal or not. This worked for me!

`ref={input => input && this.props.showModal && input.focus()}`

Comment: this works for me. but after pressing tab focus goes out of modal. Any suggestion ? @IlyaSemenov

Comment: This looks wrong -- the React docs say "Calling ref.current.focus() during render is wrong because it is a side effect. Side effects should either be placed inside an event handler or be declared with useEffect." cf. https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#focus-a-field-on-mount

Answer (score 71):

If you just want to make autofocus in React, it's simple.

```
<input autoFocus type="text" />
```

---

While if you just want to know where to put that code, answer is in componentDidMount().

v014.3

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.linkInput.focus()
}
```

> In most cases, you can attach a ref to the DOM node and avoid using findDOMNode at all.

Read the API documents here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.finddomnode

Comment: And remember to capitalize that `F`! (Note to self and others, not to answerer).

Answer (score 64):

React **16.3** added a new convenient way to handle this by creating a ref in component's constructor and use it like below:

```
class MyForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.textInput = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.textInput.current?.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input ref={this.textInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For more details about `React.createRef`, you can check [this article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#createref-api) in React blog.

**Update:**

Starting from React **16.8**, `useRef` hook can be used in function components to achieve the same result:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const MyForm = () => {
  const textInput = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    textInput.current?.focus();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={textInput} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: A small change: `textInput.current?.focus();`

Comment: if you're using typescript, make sure to type the ref: ```useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)```

Answer (score 30):

The React docs now have a section for this. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

```
 render: function() {
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={function(input) {
        if (input != null) {
          input.focus();
        }
      }} />
    );
  },
```

Comment: I think this is a good way of doing it for this particular scenario.

Comment: I didn't need to `autofocus` on mount, was just looking for the element to remain focused when entering a value. This worked perfectly for that scenario. (using react 15)

Answer (score 28):

I just ran into this issue and I'm using react <s>15.0.1</s> 15.0.2 and I'm using ES6 syntax and didn't quite get what I needed from the other answers since v.15 dropped weeks ago and some of the [`this.refs` properties were deprecated](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html#removed-deprecations) and [removed](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5495).

In general, what I needed was:

1. Focus the first input (field) element when the component mounts
2. Focus the first input (field) element with an error (after submit)

I'm using:

- React Container/Presentation Component
- Redux
- React-Router

## Focus the First Input Element

I used `autoFocus={true}` on the first `<input />` on the page so that when the component mounts, it will get focus.

## Focus the First Input Element with an Error

This took longer and was more convoluted. I'm keeping out code that isn't relevant to the solution for brevity.

#### Redux Store / State

I need a global state to know if I should set the focus and to disable it when it was set, so I don't keep re-setting focus when the components re-render (I'll be using `componentDidUpdate()` to check for setting focus.)

This could be designed as you see fit for you application.

```
{
    form: {
        resetFocus: false,
    }
}
```

#### Container Component

The component will need to have the `resetfocus` property set and a callBack to clear the property if it ends up setting focus on itself.

Also note, I organized my Action Creators into separate files mostly due to my project is fairly large and I wanted to break them up into more manageable chunks.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import MyField from '../presentation/MyField';
import ActionCreator from '../actions/action-creators';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        resetFocus: state.form.resetFocus
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        clearResetFocus() {
            dispatch(ActionCreator.clearResetFocus());
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyField);
```

#### Presentation Component

```
import React, { PropTypes } form 'react';

export default class MyField extends React.Component {
    // don't forget to .bind(this)
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._handleRef = this._handleRef.bind(this);
    }

    // This is not called on the initial render so
    // this._input will be set before this get called
    componentDidUpdate() {
        if(!this.props.resetFocus) {
            return false;
        }

        if(this.shouldfocus()) {
            this._input.focus();
            this.props.clearResetFocus();
        }
    }

    // When the component mounts, it will save a 
    // reference to itself as _input, which we'll
    // be able to call in subsequent componentDidUpdate()
    // calls if we need to set focus.
    _handleRef(c) {
        this._input = c;
    }

    // Whatever logic you need to determine if this
    // component should get focus
    shouldFocus() {
        // ...
    }

    // pass the _handleRef callback so we can access 
    // a reference of this element in other component methods
    render() {
        return (
            <input ref={this._handleRef} type="text" />
        );
    }
}

Myfield.propTypes = {
    clearResetFocus: PropTypes.func,
    resetFocus: PropTypes.bool
}
```

### Overview

The general idea is that each form field that could have an error and be focused needs to check itself and if it needs to set focus on itself.

There's business logic that needs to happen to determine if the given field is the right field to set focus to.  This isn't shown because it will depend on the individual application.

When a form is submitted, that event needs to set the global focus flag `resetFocus` to true.  Then as each component updates itself, it will see that it should check to see if it gets the focus and if it does, dispatch the event to reset focus so other elements don't have to keep checking.

*edit* 
As a side note, I had my business logic in a "utilities" file and I just exported the method and called it within each `shouldfocus()` method.

Cheers!

Comment: I tried something similar but couldn't make it work. Could you please have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64542829/focus-on-the-first-input-item-only

Answer (score 17):

This is not longer the best answer.   As of v0.13, `this.refs` may not available until AFTER `componentDidMount()` runs, in some odd cases.

Just add the `autoFocus` tag to your input field, as FakeRainBrigand showed above.

Comment: Multiple `<input autofocus>` fields won't behave nice

Comment: Of course not.  Only one focus per page.  If you have multiple autofocuses, you should check your code and intentions.

Comment: @Dave's question was about setting focus on an `<input>` after render

Comment: On autofocus, is there a way to force the iOS keyboard to open as well?

Comment: @RemiSture same questions. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 14):

Ref. @Dave's comment on @Dhiraj's answer; an alternative is to use the callback functionality of the ref attribute on the element being rendered (after a component first renders):

```
<input ref={ function(component){ React.findDOMNode(component).focus();} } />
```

[More info](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Comment: When I tried this out, I got: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null`

Comment: You have to null check the param, it will be null when the component is not mounted. So a simple `component && React.findDomNode...`. Read more about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute

Answer (score 14):

Using React Hooks / Functional components with Typescript, you can use the [`useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) with `HTMLInputElement` as the generic parameter of `useRef`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
    const inputReference = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        inputReference.current?.focus();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <input ref={inputReference} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Or if using `reactstrap`, supply `inputReference` to `innerRef` instead of `ref`:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';

export default function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
    const inputReference = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        inputReference.current?.focus();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Input innerRef={inputReference} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

This is the proper way, how to autofocus. When you use callback instead of string as ref value, it is automatically called. You got your ref available than without the need of touching the DOM using `getDOMNode`

```
render: function() {
  return <TextInput ref={(c) => this._input = c} />;
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  this._input.focus();
},
```

Comment: what about a controlled form?

Comment: @pixel67 Also. You can set reference on elements, but also components. But you must be aware of that when working with it. So you wont try to access .value of input, if you set reference on React.Component, that wrappers the html input.

Answer (score 13):

Note that none of these answers worked for me with a [material-ui TextField component](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field). Per [How to set focus to a materialUI TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949394/how-to-set-focus-to-a-materialui-textfield) I had to jump through some hoops to get this to work:

```
const focusUsernameInputField = input => {
  if (input) {
    setTimeout(() => {input.focus()}, 100);
  }
};

return (
  <TextField
    hintText="Username"
    floatingLabelText="Username"
    ref={focusUsernameInputField}
  />
);
```

Comment: Seems like if your component is animating in, the call to `focus()` has to be delayed until the end of the animation.

Comment: Worked for me, but I used `setTimeout(() => {}, 0)`; just to make cleaner the code

Comment: window.requestAnimationFrame( ()=> input.focus() ) can be used instead of setTimeout as suggested by Shi1485

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `getInputDOMNode`?? in this case...

Just simply get the `ref` and `focus()` it when component gets mounted -- **componentDidMount**...

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class myApp extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.nameInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <input ref={input => { this.nameInput = input; }} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<myApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can put that method call inside the render function. Or inside the life cycle method, `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: componentDidUpdate is what worked for my case. I needed to set the focus on a particular button after render is called.

Answer (score 7):

That one worked for me:

```
<input autoFocus={true} />
```

Answer (score 6):

I have same problem but I have some animation too, so my colleague suggest to use window.requestAnimationFrame

this is ref attribute of my element:

```
ref={(input) => {input && window.requestAnimationFrame(()=>{input.focus()})}}
```

Answer (score 5):

AutoFocus worked best for me. I needed to change some text to an input with that text on double click so this is what I ended up with:

```
<input autoFocus onFocus={this.setCaretToEnd} value={this.state.editTodo.value} onDoubleClick={this.updateTodoItem} />
```

NOTE: To fix the issue where React places the caret at the beginning of the text use this method:

```
setCaretToEnd(event) {
    var originalText = event.target.value;
    event.target.value = '';
    event.target.value = originalText;
}
```

Found here:
https://coderwall.com/p/0iz_zq/how-to-put-focus-at-the-end-of-an-input-with-react-js

Answer (score 4):

Ben Carp solution in typescript

**React 16.8 + Functional component - useFocus hook**

```
export const useFocus = (): [React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>, VoidFunction] => {
  const htmlElRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const setFocus = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (htmlElRef.current) htmlElRef.current.focus();
  }, [htmlElRef]);

  return React.useMemo(() => [htmlElRef, setFocus], [htmlElRef, setFocus]);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .getDOMNode() of a DOM node; instead, use the node directly. This DOM node was rendered by `App`.

Should be

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  this.refs.nameInput.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To move focus to a newly created element, you can store the element's ID in the state and use it to set `autoFocus`. e.g.

```
export default class DefaultRolesPage extends React.Component {

    addRole = ev => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        const roleKey = this.roleKey++;
        this::updateState({
            focus: {$set: roleKey},
            formData: {
                roles: {
                    $push: [{
                        id: null,
                        name: '',
                        permissions: new Set(),
                        key: roleKey,
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {formData} = this.state;

        return (
            <GridForm onSubmit={this.submit}>
                {formData.roles.map((role, idx) => (
                    <GridSection key={role.key}>
                        <GridRow>
                            <GridCol>
                                <label>Role</label>
                                <TextBox value={role.name} onChange={this.roleName(idx)} autoFocus={role.key === this.state.focus}/>
                            </GridCol>
                        </GridRow>
                    </GridSection>
                ))}
            </GridForm>
        )
    }
}
```

This way none of the textboxes get focus on page load (like I want), but when you press the "Add" button to create a new record, then that new record gets focus.

Since `autoFocus` doesn't "run" again unless the component gets remounted, I don't have to bother unsetting `this.state.focus` (i.e. it won't keep stealing focus back as I update other states).

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution without autofocus:

```
<input ref={ref => ref && ref.focus()}
    onFocus={(e)=>e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(e.currentTarget.value.length, e.currentTarget.value.length)}
    />
```

`ref` triggers focus, and that triggers `onFocus` to calculate the end and set the cursor accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is add the ref="some name" in the input text element and call the below function.

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.refs.field_name.focus();
}
// here field_name is ref name.

<input type="text" ref="field_name" />
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying a lot of options above with no success I've found that It was as I was `disabling` and then `enabling` the input which caused the focus to be lost.

I had a prop `sendingAnswer` which would disable the Input while I was polling the backend.

```
<Input
  autoFocus={question}
  placeholder={
    gettingQuestion ? 'Loading...' : 'Type your answer here...'
  }
  value={answer}
  onChange={event => dispatch(updateAnswer(event.target.value))}
  type="text"
  autocomplete="off"
  name="answer"
  // disabled={sendingAnswer} <-- Causing focus to be lost.
/>
```

Once I removed the disabled prop everything started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Read almost all the answer but didnt see a `getRenderedComponent().props.input`

Set your text input refs

`this.refs.username.getRenderedComponent().props.input.onChange('');`

Comment: Please further clarify your answer in the context of their code.

Answer (score 1):

**Focus using createRef for functional components**

To developers using Functional Components. This seems to suit. Focus happens on inputfield after clicking on the button. I've attached CodeSandbox link too.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const inputRef = React.createRef();
  return <>
    <input ref={inputRef} type={'text'} />
    <button onClick={() => {if (inputRef.current) { inputRef.current.focus() }}} >
      Click Here
    </button>
  </>
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-http-hfwp9t

Answer (score 1):

Set a reference on the input element and then call the `focus()` method on the ref element:

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={() => {inputRef.current.focus()}}>Focus input</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated version you can check [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
componentDidMount() {

    // Focus to the input as html5 autofocus
    this.inputRef.focus();

}
render() {
    return <input type="text" ref={(input) => { this.inputRef = input }} />
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Since there is a lot of reasons for this error I thought that I would also post the problem I was facing. For me, problem was that I rendered my inputs as content of another component.

```
export default ({ Content }) => {
  return (
  <div className="container-fluid main_container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-12 h-100">
        <Content />                                 // I rendered my inputs here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
}
```

This is the way I called the above component:

```
<Component Content={() => {
  return (
    <input type="text"/>
  );
}} />
```