# How to set focus to a Material UI TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I set the focus on a Material UI TextField component?

```
componentDidMount() {
  ReactDom.findDomNode(this.refs.myControl).focus()
}
```

I have tried the above code, but it does not work.

Comment: Added a related answer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459190/how-to-use-react-refs-to-focus-a-redux-form-field/53372707#53372707).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use the `autoFocus` prop:

```
<TextField value="some value" autoFocus />
```

It sets the `autofocus` attribute on the `<input>` element.

Comment: It works when the page loads, but not after the form is submitted.

Comment: @StefanBalan Yes this only works when the page loads. Submitting the form does not reload the page. In that case you can set the autofocus programmatically.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I add the attribute, and nothing changes. The text field is not focused on page load. Just me?

Comment: As of now, this does not work in React 18 when strict mode is on https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33004

Comment: This solution breaks the the following ESLint rule: `jsx-a11y/no-autofocus`

Comment: This works on load, but does not trigger on router navigation.

Answer (score 140):

For React 16.8.6, you should use the `inputRef` property of TextField to set focus.

```
<TextField
  inputRef={input => input && input.focus()}
/>
```

[Material UI doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props) says:

> `inputRef`: Use this property to pass a ref callback to the native input component.

The `ref` prop wouldn't work. It gives a reference to the root DOM element of the TextField which is the parent of the `<input>` element.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Remember, <TextField> is a combination of several other Material components, including <Input>, <InputLabel>, <FormControl>, etc.

Comment: This is very short for a correct answer, please add some minimal working example.

Comment: That's great, but for some reason sometimes I get `null` for `input` and have to check it. Why do I get `null`?

Comment: This works but tests give error saying- Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops

Comment: @lazy.lizard surely you have found out by now, but that's just basic react refs: when the component mounts, the ref value is a DOM element, but it is null when the component unmounts.

Comment: Note that this auto-focuses on every render. Pro: it works on router navigation. Con: anything else changes on the page and it triggers; you have to isolate it from those.

Answer (score 38):

`autoFocus` was also not working for me, perhaps since this is a component that's not mounted when the top-level component loads. I had to do something a lot more convoluted to get it to work:

```
function AutoFocusTextField(props) {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }, 100);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  return <TextField inputRef={inputRef} {...props} />;
}
```

Note that for some reason it does not work without the `setTimeout`. For more info see https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1594.

Comment: you should check if the input is available inside timeout callback. This code may throw. What would be even better is to save `setTimeout` returned id to component and on `componentWillUnmount` check if timeout is still there and clear it if so.

Comment: You can use this.setState({}, () => { input.focus() })  instead of setTimeout

Comment: For React 16.8.6, you should use the `inputRef` property of TextField to set focus. See [Material-ui doc](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props)

Comment: How is it not immediately obvious to the author of the code that this is an abhorrent hack? It should have been clear while typing `setTi...`. Just about there. **Don't copy this**, take a look at the AlienKevin's answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using material-ui TextField and react functional component, you can  pass inputRef in your TextField component. The trick here is the  if condition `if(input != null)`.

```
<TextField
    variant="filled"
    inputRef={(input) => {
      if(input != null) {
         input.focus();
      }
    }}
/>
```

Here is an working example for you. [CodeSandBox- Material-ui-TextFieldFocus](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfieldfocus-jz9gb?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 9):

This will focus the component every time it renders.  Other solutions I tried only focus the element an initial time.

```
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
  }, [inputRef.current]);

  const setTextInputRef = (element: HTMLInputElement) => {
    inputRef.current = element;
  };
   
  return (
    <TextField
      inputRef={setTextInputRef}
    />
```

Answer (score 6):

add this propery to your `TextField` component :

```
inputRef={(input) => input?.focus()}
```

Comment: if you want to focus only on condition use something like : inputRef={(input) => condition === true && input?.focus()}

Answer (score 4):

For those on the latest version of React 18 and MUI (Dec 2023)

and are using a Dialog Box.

You don't need any ref or input ref solutions.

You'll need to set `disableRestoreFocus` on the parent dialog && then set `autoFocus` as usual on the `TextField`.

```
<Dialog
        open={showNewAccountDialog}
        onClose={() => setShowNewAccountDialog(false)}
        disableRestoreFocus={true}
>
  ...
  <TextField autoFocus {...otherProps}/>
</Dialog>
```

Here's an issue that is currently being tracked:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33004#issuecomment-1473299089

Comment: This is the right solution for an Input in Dialog

Answer (score 3):

```
 const handleClick =  () => {
   inputRef.current.firstChild.focus();
   inputRef.current.firstChild.placeholder = '';
  }
  <InputBase
        value={value}
        ref={inputRef}
        placeholder="search" />
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click</Button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`useRef` hook simple example:

```
const focusMe_Ref = useRef(null); // 1. create

useEffect(() => {
  focusMe_Ref.current.focus();  // 2. startup
}, []);


...

<TextField
   inputRef={focusMe_Ref} // 3. will focused
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is actually good, but has a drawback, on every render it's going to create a new function. It easily can be solved using useCallback

```
<TextField
  inputRef={input => input && input.focus()}
/>
```

Should be

```
const callbackRef = useCallback((inputElement) => {
     if (inputElement) {
         inputElement.focus();
     }
 }, []);
...
<TextField
  inputRef={callbackRef}
/>
```

Comment: Using `useCallback` does not prevent a new function from being created on every render. it makes the value of `callbackRef` to always be the function from the first render, but all other renders will still create new functions that will not be used by anyone.

Comment: And as the cherry on the top you are also creating an additional array

Answer (score 1):

Update 2023 - with MUI v.5.14.8, you can use `focused` prop.
This prop sets the 'focused' attribute to the input element.

```
<TextField
 focused
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solution, works for text fields inspired by https://gist.github.com/carpben/de968e377cbac0ffbdefe1ab56237573

```js
const useFocus = (): [any, () => void] => {
    const htmlElRef: MutableRefObject<any> = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    const setFocus = (): void => {
        if (!htmlElRef || !htmlElRef.current) return
        const div = htmlElRef.current as HTMLDivElement
        if (!div) return
        const input = div.querySelector("input")
        if (input) input.focus()
    }
    return [htmlElRef, setFocus];
};


export function MyComp() {
  const [ref, setFocus] = useFocus()
  
  // use setFocus() to focus the input field

  return <Input ref={ref} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the input field didn't regain focus after I've modified its contents with external controls (an emoji picker).
I ended up with this brute workaround hook:

```js
const useEnforceFocusTextField = (textFieldRef: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const [enforcedRerender, setEnforcedRerender] = useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    textFieldRef.current?.focus();
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      textFieldRef.current?.focus();
    }, 100);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [enforcedRerender]);
  return () => setEnforcedRerender((n) => !n);
};
```

From the outside, you call utilize this hook in the following manner:

```js
const textFieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
...
// enforceFocus() can be called in any callback to set the focus to the textfield
const enforceFocus = useEnforceFocusTextField(textFieldRef);
...
return <TextField inputRef={textFieldRef} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript version in MUI 5 I had to use inner elements of TextField such a way

```
    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
          (((inputRef.current as unknown as HTMLElement)?.firstChild as HTMLElement)?.firstChild as HTMLElement)?.focus();      
        }
      }, 100);
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    }, [open]);
    ...
    <TextField ref={inputRef}/>
```

Answer (score -1):

For a material ui TextField you need to input the props for autoFocus in a inputProps object like this.

```
 <TextField inputProps={{ autoFocus: true }} />
```

Answer (score -2):

AlienKevin is correct ( pass a ref callback to "TextField.inputProps" ), but you can also save the element reference on your "this" object, so that you can set focus later.  Here is an example in Coffeescript:

```
TextField
    inputProps:
        ref: (el)=>
            if el?
                @input_element = el

Button
    onClick:=> 
        @input_element.focus()
```