# Autofocus TextField using React Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use [Material-UI TextField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field)

I want to implement an autofocus, I can't find a way to do it from markup by setting `autofocus=true` not programmatically. any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set focus to a materialUI TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949394/how-to-set-focus-to-a-materialui-textfield)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do this like this: `<TextField autoFocus></TextField>`.

More on this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes.

Comment: It worked just fine, thanks!
How did you know that such prop exists? Because I couldn't find it in the docs: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

Comment: This is built into React

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason. Have to use the setTimeout solution instead.

Answer (score 10):

For some reason this was not working for me (maybe because it's within a component that's not visible when the top-level component mounts). I had to do something more convoluted to get it to work:

```
const focusUsernameInputField = input => {
  if (input) {
    setTimeout(() => {input.focus()}, 100);
  }
};

return (
  <TextField
    hintText="Username"
    floatingLabelText="Username"
    ref={focusUsernameInputField}
  />
)
```

For more info see https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/1594.

Comment: "...The element must be visible in order to be focusable.

Elements of the following type are focusable if they are not disabled: input, select, textarea, button, and object. Anchors are focusable if they have an href or tabindex attribute. area elements are focusable if they are inside a named map, have an href attribute, and there is a visible image using the map. All other elements are focusable based solely on their tabindex attribute and visibility.": From https://api.jqueryui.com/focusable-selector/

Comment: Works with inputRef={focusUsernameInputField}

Answer (score 3):

You can create a reusable hook for autofocus purposes.

```
  export function useFocusableInput(shouldFocus: boolean) {
    const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
    const setInputRef = (instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => {
      inputRef.current = instance;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      let timeout: NodeJS.Timeout;
      if (shouldFocus) {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          inputRef.current?.focus();
        });
      }

      return () => {
        if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
      };
    }, [shouldFocus]);

    return {
      setInputRef,
    };
  }
```

Then use it for a desired textfield

```
const { setInputRef } = useFocusableInput(shouldFocus);
return (
...
<TextField
  inputRef={setInputRef}
  ...
/>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just simply put the ref of input into state

`<TextInput inputRef={el => { this.setState({form: el}) }}/>`

then you can set focus to the input anywhere.

`this.state.form.focus()`

Answer (score 0):

Auto focus helped so thank you for pointing that out.
however when I typed hello the text cursor kept going back to index 0 so I got olleh as the value here is how I resolved this I used onFocus to change the text cursor to the end of the text.

```
 return <Textarea autoFocus aria-label="empty textarea" placeholder="Empty" value={props.textValue}
    onFocus={(event) => {
        const valueLength = event.target.value.length;
        event.target.setSelectionRange(valueLength, valueLength);
    }}
    onChange={(event) => {
        props.setValue((prev) => {
            return {
                ...prev,
                [props.textValueKey]: event.target.value

            }
        });
    }} />;
```

}