# HTML textarea inside ReactJS component can't be programmatically selected without setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a ReactJS component with an HTML `<textarea>` inside.

The `<textarea>` has the `value` attribute pre-populated (see below ... I'm generating a link for the user to copy).

I want to automatically select the `<textarea>` content so it'll be more convenient for the user to copy the text.  I'm trying to do this in the React `componentDidMount` call.  It works... *sort of*.

As near as I can tell, the component is mounting so slowly that the process is still ongoing even when `componentDidMount` is already being called.  The reason I say this is: if I call `myTextarea.select()` directly within `componentDidMount`, it *fails* 100% of the time.  However, if I put `.select()` in a `setTimeout(...)` call so it waits a bit before trying to select the content, it *works* 100% of the time.

*Edit/note: after poking around a little more, I've discovered some sentiment indicating that using `setTimeout(...)` for this purpose is poor practice, so now I'm even more eager to avoid using it.*

What might I be missing, and is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here's what I have.

**This version fails.**

```
var GenerateLinkUi = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    document.getElementById('cyoag-generated-link-textarea').select();
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id='cyoag-generate-link-ui'>
        <textarea readOnly id='cyoag-generated-link-textarea' value={config.hostDomain + 'link?id=' + this.props.nodeUid} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

**This version succeeds.**

```
var GenerateLinkUi = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('cyoag-generated-link-textarea').select();
    }, 500);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id='cyoag-generate-link-ui'>
        <textarea readOnly id='cyoag-generated-link-textarea' value={config.hostDomain + 'link?id=' + this.props.nodeUid} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Edit: this was flagged as a duplicate. The linked question raises more questions for me, and does not provide a clear answer, as discussed in comments below. If `ref` executes after the component mounts, and `componentDidMount` also executes "after" component mounting, I struggle to understand the difference between the two, beyond the fact that `ref` is passed a DOM element as an arg; where in `componentDidMount` I'd have to use `document.getElementById` or something. I'd appreciate if anyone could describe deeper differences between the two.

In the meantime I've found other workarounds for this issue but I'm still eager to learn more on the subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React set focus on input after render](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess at what's happening.

Does the component get rendered after `componentDidMount` again? I imagine it will render the `textarea` again and overwrite the `select()` because you have done it on the actual DOM and not the virtual.

It works when using setTimeout because you do it after all of the renders that occurred after `componentDidMount`. I imagine if you updated the props again it would overwrite the `select()` again.

Use refs to solve this.

```
var GenerateLinkUi = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.textArea.select();
  },
  setTextArea: function(ref) {
    this.textArea = ref;
  }
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div id='cyoag-generate-link-ui'>
        <textarea ref={this.setTextArea} readOnly id='cyoag-generated-link-textarea' value={config.hostDomain + 'link?id=' + this.props.nodeUid} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I found a workaround in the meantime; but I'm trying to understand this answer because seems on the right track. If there are subsequent renders being triggered, I can't find what's causing. I suppose it's possible. My question then is, if `ref` executes after the component mounts, and `componentDidMount` also executes after component mounting, I struggle to understand the difference between the two, other than the fact that `ref` is passed a DOM element as an arg; where in `componentDidMount` I'd have to use `document.getElementById` or something.

Comment: @Steverino The difference between using `ref` and `document.getElementById` is that React can see the changes you make on the `ref` because it is modifying the virtual DOM that is rendered. React can't see the changes you make on the actual DOM so it overwrites it with the virtual DOM which doesn't have the `select()` on it.

Remember the `<textarea />` that you render is a virtual DOM element and different to the actual DOM element rendered on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The technique to do so is called [refs callback](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any component. The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted or unmounted.

BTW, you are using the correct `componentDidMount` method.

---

Refs are there for you

[image]

It is present in the ReactClass.