# Mobx and React. How to handle focus input after observable change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mobx

with React state it was easy to set new value which was condition for render some input and then focus to that input with state callback.

```
handleToggleInput() {
  const showInput = !this.state.showInput
  this.setState({ showInput }, () => showInput && this.refs.input.focus())
}

render() {
  if(this.state.showInput) {
    <input ref="input" type="text />
  }
}
```

Now when switching to Mobx it is not possible

```
@observable showInput = false;

handleToggleInput() {
  this.showInput = !this.showInput
  this.showInput && this.refs.input.focus()
}

render() {
  if(this.showInput) {
    <input ref="input" type="text />
  }
}
```

This will fail, because React did not yet rerender component with input.
Is there any way how wait and detect when rerender is done?

Comment: Very interesting. It works if you [**defer the focus**](http://jsbin.com/kuzariquce/edit?js,output). If you don't conditionally hide the input, it works without the defer. Hopefully a MobX pro can shine some light on this.

Comment: @Tholle Very clever! This probably works now fine, but in future with React Fiber or other React implementation can be problem because of rerender scheduling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback in `setState` will run after the state is set and the component is re-rendered. MobX has no equivalent. So use this method to do the focus after React has re-rendered the UI.

```
componentDidUpdate: function(prevProps, prevState){
   this.refs.input.focus(); 
},
```

To run code immediately after first render

```
componentDidMount: function(){
   this.refs.input.focus(); 
},
```

[React set focus on input after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render)

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Also start using the ref callback, as shown in the StackOverflow question. Using `ref="input"` is deprecated.

Comment: But there I dont know the observable transition from "not show" to "show". ComponentDidUpdate can be triggered from million of other reasons. Only solution, but ugly one is to keep some property `this._focusOnUpdate = showInput` in handler and then reflect in it lifecycle event. But as I said it is ugly :(

Comment: If you want a newly appearing input, why not use `autofocus` attribute for that input?

Comment: Autofocus is neat and simple, but it became pretty complex when I `showInput` is true on first render, but I dont want to focus there. My initial question was more generic, how to react (in any way) to rerender after observable change.