# Control Focus of Multiple FormControl Fields

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a mapped list of input fields:

```
                      <FormControl
                            name={row_index}
                            value={barcode.barcode}
                            placeholder="Barcode - then Enter"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress}
                            disabled={barcode.submitted}
                        />
```

I am currently using `onKeyPress` to handle submit:

```
_handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const barcodes = this.state.barcodes;
        const this_barcode = barcodes[name];

        let apiFormatted = {"barcode": this_barcode.barcode, "uid": this.props.currentSession}
        this.postBarcodeAPI(apiFormatted, name)
    }
}
```

I am attempting to focus on the **next** input field after the current one is successfully submitted. React documentation [has an example](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) for manually setting focus on a single input field using `ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />`. I have tried using `this[‘textInput’+‘1’].focus()` (using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), but am getting an error that function is invalid.

**EDIT**

Per Chase's answer, I am linking to the autofocus documentation, [although it doesn't work in this case](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1692).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/autofocus

Comment: Does my answer not work anymore? Looks like it was removed as the answer.

Comment: Part of it doesn't work, see my comment. But I re-accepted answer for alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My working solution:

```
const focusing = index === lastSubmittedIndex + 1 ? true : false;
const refText = focusing || index === 0 ? input => input && input.focus() : null;

                        <FormControl
                            name={row_index}
                            value={barcode.barcode}
                            placeholder="Barcode - then Enter"
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress}
                            disabled={barcode.submitted || barcode.apiCalling}
                            inputRef={refText}
                        />
```

What I corrected in my code:
 1) I am supposed to use `inputRef` instead of `ref` for Bootstrap's FormControl component, [see here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-props-form-control).
 2) I am using ilya-semenov's very neat [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40235334/4822174).

**Update**
I have other buttons on the page, when user presses them and is at bottom of page, page jumps up to top. Not sure why.

Comment: Hmm, okay so you are hacking the ref prop. Dirty but it works lol

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've set a ref with the key `textInput1` then this won't work. Another suggestion would be to move all of the inputs into a separate component and then you can use `this.props.children` to traverse all your inputs and grab the input at whatever position you want.

EDIT:

You can also use the `autoFocus` prop to determine if an input should be focused or not.

Comment: autoFocus doesn't work: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1692. So storing ref's is the way to go.

Comment: sorry, retracting again, i found a different solution which works for me