# How to trigger focus event programatically in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, onfocus

I'm trying to trigger focus event programatically:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  function focusTrig() {
    ref.current.focus();
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <button onClick={focusTrig}>Focus trigger</button>

      <div ref={ref} onFocus={() => console.log("FOCUSED!")}>
        Focus Target
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-bird-qw3nh6?file=/src/App.js:0-468)

The `console.log` binded with the `onFocus` event never run. Why?

**UPDATE**
If I turn the target element from DIV to INPUT, the the console.log get run. But this openly conflicts with the official documentation, that states:

> These focus events work on all elements in the React DOM, not just
> form elements.

[ReactJS 17 DOC](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/events.html#focus-events)

Comment: see if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43145549/how-react-programmatically-focus-input

Answer (score 1):

Add **[tabIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)** to the `div` element which indicates that it can be focused

```
<div tabIndex="0" ref={ref} onFocus={() => {console.log("FOCUSED!")}}>
        Focus Target
      </div>
```