# Make LI element auto focus in react

Tags: reactjs

How to add autofocus property in LI element in react? I've used through ref but is not working.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <li ref={(re) => re.focus()}>aaa</li>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React set focus on input after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `componentDidMount` and focusing the ref inside that function.

Also, like Tomasz said, an `li` element is not focusable, so you would need to use an input, button, or anchor-type element to be able to focus.

Example:
[React set focus on input after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render)

Answer (score 0):

Focus works only on controls like input, button, anchors. You can't do it on list elements, divs etc. Maybe just make it a button? Clickable elements should be buttons / anchors.

Comment: Not really. List elements, divs etc can be focusable. You can read more about `tabindex` html attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex