# styled component input focus

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to focus on the input when the component mounts. The input component is a styled component, therefore I use innerRef to get the reference to the element. However the input does not get focus when the component mounts. I have checked that the node is actually getting the reference to the DOM node. I m not able to find any issue with my logic. Thank you for your help.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const UrlInput = styled.input`
  width: 400px;
  height: 34px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font: 400 14px 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
  ::placeholder {
    color: rgb(100,100,100);
    font: 400 14px 'Source Sans Pro', 'sans-serif';
  }
`

class AddUrl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url: ''
    }
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const node = findDOMNode(this.inputRef.current);
    node && node.focus();
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <AddUrlWrapper>
        <UrlInput placeholder={"Paste URL here"}
          innerRef={this.inputRef}
          type="text"
          value={this.state.url}
          onChange={(event) => this.setState({url: event.target.value})}/>
        <FetchButton>Fetch</FetchButton>
      </AddUrlWrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/react-set-focus-on-input-after-render

Comment: I don't think so, but thanks for checking. Styled component makes things a bit tricky.

Comment: Have you tried creating the ref with the fat arrow directly inline `ref={(input) => { this.inputRef = input; }} `
and focus the element using simply `this.inputRef.focus();` ?

Answer (score 4):

For styled components, use the prop `innerRef` instead of `ref`. Got it from their docs [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/tips-and-tricks.md).

Example from the doc:

```
<StyledInput innerRef={this.input} />
```

Gave it a try, it works

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const UrlInput = styled.input`
  background-color: white;
`;

class AddUrl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.inputRef.current) {
      this.inputRef.current.focus(); // This should work
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <UrlInput innerRef={this.inputRef} />
    )
  }
}
```

You can use `ref` instead of `innerRef` if you switch to React v16 and styled components v4

```
<UrlInput ref={this.inputRef} />
```

And also please check this

> Native support for ref on any styled component, no more innerRef thanks to React v16

https://medium.com/styled-components/announcing-styled-components-v4-better-faster-stronger-3fe1aba1a112

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` did the trick.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const node = findDOMNode(this.inputRef.current);
    setTimeout(() => node && node.focus(), 0);
  }
```