# How to focus on child element component on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using react-bootstrap and importing component modal when I click on the modal button, the modal pops up but I want the focus to directly go to the input field inside the modal when open modal button is clicked, which I am not able to achieve

I have tried putting attribute as autoFocus and also tried to use refs but did not succeed as of now.

**The child component**

```
 <Modal

    aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
    centered
  >

    <Modal.Body>
      <h4>File Name</h4>
      <input autoFocus aria-label="File name entering field"  className="form-control mt-3" name="term" type="text"  />
    </Modal.Body>

  </Modal>
```

**the parent that triggers the child**

```
 <Button 
          variant="dark"
          onClick={() => {this.setState({ modalShow: true }); } }
        >
        popper
        </Button>

        <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
          show={this.state.modalShow}
          onHide={modalClose}
          saver= {this.saveDataImage}
        />
```

I want the focus to directly go to the input field in the modal to have good accessibility

Comment: please check your answer here 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/set-focus-on-input-after-render`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` as mentioned here: [useRef docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Answer (score 0):

in your INPUT component that you want to focus, you should add the property "autoFocus"
for example:

```
<input autoFocus id=... name=.../>
```

for more information check: 
[Set focus on input after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/set-focus-on-input-after-render)

Answer (score 0):

We can create a [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to our `input` element and when the component that mounts the `input` element mounts, we can use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook to focus our input.

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
  };

  render() {
    return <input ref={this.inputRef} type="text" />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Asaf, I tried this but it gives me an error , TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Comment: @Harry If you can make a simple example on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with just the components that triggers the `Modal` i will happily take a look at it

Comment: I tired making a simple example but it's giving me a cross origin error and I am getting stuck. Thanks for your help anyway Asaf