# ReactJS and autofocus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap, autofocus

I have a `react-bootstrap` modal with an `<input>`. I want to set the autofocus attribute on the `<input>`

The following **works fine**, but shows a warning in the console

```
<input type="text" autofocus='true' />
```

```
Warning: Invalid DOM property `autofocus`. Did you mean `autoFocus`?
```

The following options **do not work**, in the sense that they do not focus the input when opening the modal:

```
<input type="text" autoFocus='true' />
<input type="text" autoFocus={true} />
<input type="text" autoFocus />
```

What is the recommended way of setting autofocus. Or how should I mute the warnings for the example that works well?

Note: This is react 16.8.6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set focus on an input field after rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/how-to-set-focus-on-an-input-field-after-rendering)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Refs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is what you want,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.myRef.current.focus();
}

<input type="text"  ref={this.myRef} />
```

Comment: I was hoping there is some more HTML way. But the variant I claimed "worked" doesn't actually work when you open the modal for the second time.

Comment: `componentDidMount` work in mounting phase only, when you reopen your modal then your component don't go through `componentDidMount` function and you will not get focus here. For that you need some other lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: You can still use `autoFocus` if you have `ref={this.setMyRef}`, the `setMyRef` handler being a function that sets the implicitly passed input ref as a parameter bound to the input html element. It makes sense to create a wrapper component for input element for these cases.

Comment: Yes, you can do so. Refer the `Callback Refs` section from link I have provided in answer.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using React Hooks, add `useCallback()` to your component and add a `ref={callback}` to the form control:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'

function InputComponent() {
    const autoFocus = useCallback(el => el ? el.focus() : null, [])

    return <input type="text" ref={autoFocus} />
}

export default InputComponent
```

You can replace the `<input>` with a React Bootstrap `FormControl` too.

Comment: Awesome solution.

Comment: Why are using `useCallback` instead of `useRef` here? Isn't `useCallback` rather for the purpose of keeping the identity of callbacks to avoid unnecessary re-renders? My understanding was that the use case here requires rather `useRef` + `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react hooks, you could write your own simple auto focus hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useAutoFocus = (inputId: string) => {
    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!initialized) {
            document.getElementById("email").focus();
            setInitialized(true);
        }
    });
};
```

and the simply use e.g.

```
useAutoFocus("email")
```

in your form.

Comment: What if the inputId changes? You probably want to use a dependency array with useEffect instead of relying on useState.

Comment: This is only for initial focus because newest react throws an error with html attribute autofocus even if it works physically. Feel free to adjust to your needs!

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding an `autoFocus` prop did the trick:

```html
<input autoFocus {...} />
```