# Conver myRef to hooks version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autofocus

I found this answer: [ReactJS and autofocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56896201/reactjs-and-autofocus)

but I don't know how to convert this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.myRef.current.focus();
}

<input type="text"  ref={this.myRef} />
```

to react hooks version.

I tried doing this:

```
const myRef = () => {
  React.createRef().current.focus();
}

<input type="text"  ref={myRef} />
```

but got error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) you'll need to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) too which runs after a render. The `[]` means that [it only runs once](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function Component() {

  const ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.focus();
  }, []);

  return <input type="text"  ref={ref} />;

}
```