# Trying to use React.createRef() but getting error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus, autofocus

## The code in the file is:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class LoginModal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.mobileInput = React.createRef();    // <------------CREATED REF Here
    }

   componentDidMount() {
        this.mobileInput.current.focus()        // <<<------------Getting ERROR here
   }

render() {
        return (
          <input
            type='number'
            onChange={this.handleInputChange('mobile')}
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Enter mobile'
            name='mobile'
            ref={this.mobileInput}           // <<<------------added ref to input
         />
       )
    }
```

The error that I am getting is:

### TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

what I have tried:

- I have tried to use the autofocus prop, that doesn't seem to work in my current project setup.
- Tried to use componentDidUpdate instead of componentDidMount.

*There is more code in the file. I have removed unnecessary code for clarity.

Comment: Your code works fine, can you post the full code?

Comment: @ChrisG Why would you say that without any evidence of it working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set focus on input after render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/set-focus-on-input-after-render)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava You mean evidence like the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-cookies-fsf93) I set up before posting my comment? 

Comment: @ChrisG Yes exactly :)

Comment: Here is the complete files code @ChrisG https://pastebin.com/aj1MciHJ

Comment: No that link doesn't help @AnuragSrivastava , I tried it, still no progress

Comment: I updated the sandbox, the code works as expected (refresh the codesandbox browser). I suspect the error occurs because the input isn't always rendered, so the solution is to check for `.current` being `!== null` before calling `focus()` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I found the answer. Just have to use this.

```js
<input ref={input => input && input.focus()}/>
```