# How to call a Parent method in Child Component using Hook (ForwardRef concept)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried the following code but it fails
So, this is my Parent Component:

```
    import React from 'react'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

const ParentComponent = (props) => {

    //step 1
    // const inputRef = React.createRef();
    const buttonRef = React.useRef();
    const focusHandler = () => {
        alert("hi");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {/* In parent, we generally pass reference to child which we dint do here, lets see if props children help here */}
            {props.children}
            <ChildComponent ref="buttonRef" />

        </div>
    )
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

This is my child component:

```
import React from 'react'

const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={ref.focusHandler}>Focus Input</button>      
        </div>
    )
})

export default ChildComponent;
```

On click of the button above in child component, I wish to call Parent method.
How can that be achieved?
EDITED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because refs in function components need to be passed using `ref={buttonRef}`, not `ref="buttonRef"`. Class components have a thing they can do with string refs, but it's not recommended even there.

As for calling a function from a parent component, you don't need refs to do this. So if that was the only reason you were using a ref, you can remove the ref. Instead, pass the function as a prop:

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    const focusHandler = () => {
        alert("hi");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ChildComponent focusHandler={focusHandler} />
        </div>
    )
}

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.focusHandler}>Focus Input</button>      
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was a silly mistake.
Although, have corrected it. No more getting that error. 
But, after that, the error is but the main query, not able to receive alert.
Have changed button to 
<button onClick={ref.focusHandler}>Focus Input</button>    
But this didn't help either

Comment: Still, wanted to do this via ForwardRef concept if you know. This is basic concept in which prop is being passed

Comment: ForwardRef is not about passing data from the parent to the child, and you should not use it for that. The purpose of forward ref is so that the *parent* component can get a reference to a dom element in the *child* component. Usually it would be the outermost dom element (the child's `<div>` in your case). This is for the parent's benefit, not the child's. It lets the parent then do imperative things things like call `.focus` on that element, or scroll the element into view

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `ref` by `focusHandler` like below in parent component

```
<ChildComponent focusHandler={focusHandler} />
```

Then in `ChildComponent`, remove `ref` as well.

Comment: This dint help either
In child component, still onClick event ref is to be triggered right? How? 
  <button onClick={ref}>Focus Input</button>
If ref is "focusHandler" as you mentioned

Comment: I mean no need to use `ref` at all in your `ChildComponent`, just ONLY need `focusHandler`.

Comment: Another related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/how-to-set-focus-on-an-input-field-after-rendering

Comment: import React from 'react'

const ChildComponent = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={}>Focus Input</button>      
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChildComponent;
What's to be written **onClick** ?

Comment: Just like this:

```<button onClick={props.focusHandler}>Focus Input</button>```

Answer (score 1):

If you wonder how to use refs in this case (**even though this is not the recommended way to pass callbacks**), you need to assign `focusHandler` key and use the ref with `ref.current`, [refer to Components and Props docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const buttonRef = React.useRef({ focusHandler: () => alert("hi") });

  return (
    <div>
      <ChildComponent ref={buttonRef} />
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={ref.current.focusHandler}>Focus Input</button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit blissful-leaf-emm72]

Comment: Thanks!! 
what do we do if we have ChildComponent in main page as
<ParentComponent>
 <ChildComponent/>
<ParentComponent>

and the method is in ParentComponent

Comment: Don't understand the question, anyway you should just post a new question with some context.

Comment: Try reading the answer until the end "you don't need refs to pass callbacks" OP especially asks how to use `forwardRef`

Comment: @NicholasTower She even told it in her own comment for your answer: "Still, wanted to do this via ForwardRef concept if you know. This is basic concept in which prop is being passed "