# How to focus TextInput on button press in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a TextInput component, which is only editable on component mount. It should become editable and auto focused, when a button is pressed. As I understood it correctly, the `autoFocus` property only works on first mount. Is there any way to implement this on state change?

```js
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';


interface InputTextBoxProps {
  editingState: boolean;
}

type InputProps = TextInputProps & InputTextBoxProps;

const InputTextBox: FunctionComponent<InputProps> = ({editingState, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        {...props}
        multiline={true} 
        style={styles.textStyle}
        editable={editingState}
        autoFocus={editingState}
      >
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set focus on an input field after rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889826/how-to-set-focus-on-an-input-field-after-rendering)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
const refInput = React.useRef(null);
 ...
<TextInput
  {...props}
  ref={refInput}
  multiline={true} 
  style={styles.textStyle}
  editable={editingState}>
</TextInput>
```

on button click function

```
refInput.current.focus()
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Here's the working solution, as the `editable` prop seems to work only on component mount, so it won't change via state. This solution is built on [mainak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8243241/mainak)'s answer.

```js
import { FunctionComponent, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';

interface InputTextBoxProps {
  editingState: boolean;
}

type InputProps = TextInputProps & InputTextBoxProps;

const InputTextBox: FunctionComponent<InputProps> = ({editingState, ...props}) => {

  const refInput = useRef<TextInput>(null);

  if (editingState) {
    refInput.current?.focus();
  } else {
    refInput.current?.blur();
  }

  return (
    <View pointerEvents={editingState ? 'auto' : 'none'}>
      <TextInput
        {...props}
        ref={refInput}
        multiline={true}
      >
      </TextInput>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoFocus` which works fine for me

```
const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState(false);

<TextInput
     placeholder="Search Manifest ID"
     style={styles.SearchInput}
     placeholderTextColor={'#808080'}
     value={search}
     onChangeText={setSearch}
     onSubmitEditing={() => { onSubmitted(); }}
    autoFocus={focusedInput} // here its working for me
/>
```